# Logistic differential equation with intermittent exploit rate

Tags: differential-equations

I'm working with the differential equation:

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=rP(1-\frac{P}K)-H(t)$$
$$P(0)=P_0$$

where $r$ and $K$ are known values. The idea is that $H(t)$ is a piecewise function such that from $t=0, H(t)=H_0$ (also a known value) but when $P(t)$ is below a certain value $p_1$ then $H(t)=0$ until $P(t)$ is greater than a certain value $p_2>p_1$.

After this, $H(t)=H_0$ again until $P(t)$ is below $p1$, and so on. I think the graph of the $P(t)$ function should look like a zig-zagging line.

I've been trying to numerically solve such equation but I don't know how to code such function.
The only way I can think of describing such function $H(t)$ is by using a boolean variable that keeps track of the growth of $P$, but I don't think I can do that inside the NDSolve function.

Any ideas on how H would be so 
`NDSolve[{P'[t] == r (1 - P[t]/K)*P[t] - H[t], P[0] == P0}, P, {t, 0, 20}]`
doesn't outputs errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this using `NDSolve` with two `WhenEvent`s, with `H[t]` as a `DiscreteVariable`.

Variables:

```
ClearAll[p, t, H];
p0 = 1/2;
p1 = 1;
p2 = 2;
H0 = 5;
k = 10;
r = 1/2;
```

Differential equation and initial conditions:

```
ode = {p'[t] == r p[t] (1 - p[t]/k) - H[t],
  WhenEvent[p[t] == p2(*&&p'[t]>0*), H[t] -> H0],
  WhenEvent[p[t] == p1(*&&p'[t]<0*), H[t] -> 0]};
ic = {p[0] == p0, H[0] == 0};
```

Solving the equation:

```
sols = NDSolve[Join[ode, ic], {p[t], H[t]}, {t, 0, 30}, DiscreteVariables -> H];
```

Then, we can plot the solution:

```
GraphicsRow@{Plot[p[t] /. sols, {t, 0, 30}], Plot[H[t] /. sols, {t, 0, 30}]}
```

[image]

Note that if `H0` is too small, the derivative won't change sign, and so it won't go back and forth:

```
H0 = 0.5;
sols = NDSolve[Join[ode, ic], {p[t], H[t]}, {t, 0, 30}, DiscreteVariables -> H];
GraphicsRow@{Plot[p[t] /. sols, {t, 0, 30}], Plot[H[t] /. sols, {t, 0, 30}]}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know the existence of WhenEvent. That makes life so much easier. Probably there's no way to do such equation without it. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me!