# Poincaré section for non-autonomous logistic equation with periodic harvesting

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, nonlinear, ecology

I'd like to plot the Poincaré section based on the problem from here: [see exercise 8.1](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Erauch/558/dimension1.5.pdf)

Given that the standard logistic equation with harvesting function is
$$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = ax(1 - x) - h (1 + \sin{2 \pi t})$$
with parameters $a >0, h>0$.

From some reading [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/40139/75304) and [also here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57862/75304)
I try to manipulate some points with $a=5, h=0.8$

```
Manipulate[{sol, samples} = 
Reap@NDSolve[{x'[t] == 
5*x[t]*(1 - x[t]) - 0.8*(1 + Sin[2*\[Pi]*t]), 
x[0] == 1, WhenEvent[Mod[t, delT] == 0, Sow[{t, x[t]}]]}, 
    x, {t, 10}];

Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}, Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Red, 
    Point @@ samples}], {{delT, .1}, .01, 0.5}, 
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

With `delT=0.3` I got:

[image]

then I started to lost.

**Question 1** How to plot from here? I (try to) allocate the points to map the Poincaré section, but I'm not sure if this is a correct protocol for first order DE

```
data = {x'[t] == 5* x[t]*(1 - x[t]) - 0.8*(1 + Sin[2*\[Pi]*t])};
psect[{x0_}] := Reap[NDSolve[{data, x[0] == x0 ,
     WhenEvent[Mod[t, 0.3] == 0, Sow[{t, x[t]}]]}, x, {t, 50}]];
adata = Map[psect, {0.92, 0.85, 0.76}];
ListPlot[adata, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

which I didn't get any result from here.

**Question 2**
What if, say parameter $h$ is normally distributed on the interval of $[5, 50]$ on each $t$-values. This is motivated from the discussion [of logistic with (constant) harvesting in here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/216104/75304)
where @march gave a really nice result using `DiscreteVariable`

So if I have this distribution as periodic (but random) $h$

```
delt = {RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[20, 2], 30]};
ListPlot[delt, Filling -> Axis, PlotStyle -> Red, DataRange -> {5, 50}]
```

which produce

[image]

**edit** Note that, each $t$ on the graph is distributed randomly with interval of 1, which also can be specified using `Table`.

How can I tabulate this result into $x'[t]$?

I try with `WhenEvent` and `DiscreteVariable` but didn't get anything, I might have confuses myself along the way

Comment: Please don't use LaTeX for diacritics. It makes it impossible to find this post by searching that for that keyword. Use a proper Unicode é.

Comment: @Szabolcs I wasn't aware about it, thanks for editing it out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1: Read the manual about "Reap". Here is the working code:

```
data = {x'[t] == 5*x[t]*(1 - x[t]) - 0.8*(1 + Sin[2*\[Pi]*t])};
psect[x0_] := 
  Reap[NDSolve[{data, x[0] == x0, 
      WhenEvent[Mod[t, 0.3] == 0, Sow[{t, x[t]}]]}, x, {t, 50}]][[2, 
    1]];
adata = Map[psect, {0.92, 0.85, 0.76}];
```

[image]

Question 2: MMA can not solve if `h` is too large. Reducing the mean of h gives (another run will create different output because h is stochastic):

```
h := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 2]];
data := {x'[t] == 5*x[t]*(1 - x[t]) - h *(1 + Sin[2*\[Pi]*t])};
psect[x0_] := 
  Reap[NDSolve[{data, x[0] == x0, 
      WhenEvent[Mod[t, 0.3] == 0, Sow[{t, x[t]}]]}, x, {t, 50}]][[2, 
    1]];
adata = Map[psect, {0.92, 0.85, 0.76}];
ListPlot[adata, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

Comment: oh right, I use `Reap` but didn't specify the value. I realize that the normal distributed $h$ is still producing a single (but random) value every run. But, I'm looking for multiple distributed values of $h$s on each $t$ (like the second picture in my post) on every run, my guessing is I need to create a combination of tabulated arrays of values to create that? I'm still not sure, I'm editing the description on my post to make it clearer

Comment: I think, every time h is used you get another value. To make this more explicitly, you could write: `h[t_] := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 2]];`

Answer (score 1):

For Question 1:

```
data = {x'[t] == 5*x[t]*(1 - x[t]) - 0.8*(1 + Sin[2*\[Pi]*t])};
solution = 
  Reap[sol = 
     NDSolve[{data, x[0] == 1, 
       WhenEvent[Mod[t, 0.3] == 0, Sow[{t, x[t]}]]}, x, {t, 0, 50}, 
      MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]]][[-1, 1]];
ListPlot[solution]
```